# How can I check if a array contains multiple elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, counting

I am trying to see if an array contains multiple values at any given index in the array, and if it does I want it to return true and if not return false. I want it to return true when it finds the numbers 1-9 and false if it does not.

```
 bool isSolved(int a[], int size) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (hasNum(a,size,i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }
}

bool hasNum(int a[], int size, int num) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (a[j] == num) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far and it just gets stuck and never ends.

Comment: Your loop in `hasNum` always returns on the first iteration. You probably meant to only `return false;` at the end of the function.

Comment: `if (…) return true; else return false;` should *always* be written as `return …;`.

Comment: @JJaco It is unclear what you are trying to determine for a given array. Whether the array shall contain all numbers from other array?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with it but it should terminate eventually so long size is not very large.

Comment: Appear to be trying to find matches in a 2D square matrix but are using 1D arrays amongst the other problems described by previous commenters. For instance this `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) ` does not use `i` anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to have 2 for loops in your `hasNum` function. Also, you are returning false if any of the values in the array is not equal to the number passed. You need to return false after the for loop ends.

Rewrite your `hasNum` function as shown below:

```
bool hasNum(int a[], int size, int num) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Man, that's C++. So use a standard vector and the count_if function from the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> a { /* fill vector */ };
std::count_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](auto const& x){ return x == 1;});
```

Return the number of elements with value `1`.

Also good, to question whether there's any value of `1`:

```
std::any_of(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](auto const& x){ return x == 1;});
```

I know this is strictly not an answer ...

Comment: `std::find` would be simpler in this case and they can work with arrays just fine.

Comment: @Slava: Not sure about that. Do you really prefer the `std::find(...) != std::end(a)` syntax to the stuff above? –

Comment: It would not require lambda, so it would me simpler to write and read and I think show intention better. But that is my humble opinion I did not say your answer is wrong.

Comment: For arrays - your suggestion to use `std::vector` is valid but it may sound like you must use it to use `std::count_if` etc. So I would reword that a little.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to see if an array contains multiple values at any given index in the array

An array always contains exactly one value in every index.

Comment: Really? This is what you consider a helpful answer?

Comment: No, this is what I consider a funny answer. And it's true.

Comment: @Rotem nothing wrong with a joke. Even if it is a logical joke.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code is far from any C++ guidelines.

First, you don't pass array in C++ as `int a[]`. Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Second your algorithm is badly inefficient. Consider using histogram approach.

```
bool isSolved(const std::vector<int>& a)
{
     std::array<bool,10> hist;
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
         hist[i]=false;
     }
     for(auto x : a)
     {
         if(x>=0 && x<10)
         {
              hist[x] = true;
         }
     }

     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
         if(!hist[i]) return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Suggesting the use of STL is fine, but it goes in a comment. Many questions asked here have constraints to use fundamental type arrays instead of containers. Finding out if that is the case is also the subject of a comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Absent specification to the contrary, the default assumption when answering a question is that the entire language is available.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it is sad that in Uni's and Collages they teach such worthless crap.
And it isn't hard to replace `std::array` with `bool hist[10]` and `std::vector<int>` with `int *a, size_t n`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with STL or an array of fundamental types. Understanding what the questioner needs is the operative question.

Comment: @ DavidC.Rankin one of basic answers to noob-style questions: you do something fundamentally wrong. It's better that people understand this rather than the opposite - learn to write horrible code, which is unfortunately taught at various places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to the solution to your problem:

```
class BinaryTreeSet : public BinarySearchTree {
    ...
    operator==
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are best off using std algorithms like find_if:

```
#include <algorithm>
int a[42]; // or vector<int> a(42) or any other container of any size
std::find_if(std::begin(a),std::end(a),[](auto const& v){return (v>=1)&&(v<=9);});
```